# can SKStoreProductViewController loadProductWithParameters run in background?

Tags: ios, background

every one knows that skstoreproductviewcontroller's loadproductwithparamters method need to ask app informations from web,so it load very slow,is there any method to run loadproductwithparameters in background to show the app information fast?

Answer (score 0):

The information will naturally load in the background and the intention is that you call `loadProductWithParameters:completionBlock:` before you actually want to display the view (and you can use the completion block to either show the view or to tag the item as being available to show).

Comment: i try call loadProductWithParameters:completionBlock: and in completion block tag the item finish,but i find there is no url request at all.